# Existence of solution of ODE on whole real line .

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE $$ y'=f(t,y) , y(a)=b $$ I want to know conditions on $f$ or on solution so that solution exist on whole real line $\mathbb{R}$. Only I know are the following

1. If solution is monotone and bounded then solution exist on whole real line.

2 . If $f$ is globally Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ then solution exist on whole real line.

Please suggest on other such type of properties or give some references. Thanks a lot .

Comment: There are some dependence on initial values too ,I think. Check out the example $5$. http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~tyson/existence.pdf